# ClickOnce Store metadata "AppType" is not valid

Tags: deployment, registry, clickonce

I have app that uses ClickOnce deployment.  It works on about a dozen machines but one.  I am getting following error.  I found solution from http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.distributed_apps/msg/42d44ffe781d3610, but it requires go to the registry and delete AppType, which is not the best solution, because every time I have new version, it will fail again.

Does anybody has any idea about this type of error, and how to deal with it.

Thanks a lot.

Sincerely,
Vlad.

==========================================
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
 Windows    : 5.1.2600.131072 (Win32NT)
 Common Language Runtime  : 2.0.50727.3053
 System.Deployment.dll   : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
 mscorwks.dll    : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
 dfdll.dll    : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
 dfshim.dll    : 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

SOURCES
 Deployment url   : file://xxx\yyy.application

ERROR SUMMARY
 Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
 * Activation of file://\xxx\yyy.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
  + Store metadata "AppType" is not valid.
  + Input string was not in a correct format.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
 No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
 There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
 * [5/20/09 12:22:26 PM] : Activation of file://\xxx\yyy.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
 Following errors were detected during this operation.
 * [5/20/09 12:22:27 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (SubscriptionState)
  - Store metadata "AppType" is not valid.
  - Source: System.Deployment
  - Stack trace:
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetPropertyAppType(DefinitionAppId appId, String propName)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionState.Validate()
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionState.get_IsInstalled()
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
   at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
  --- Inner Exception ---
  System.FormatException
  - Input string was not in a correct format.
  - Source: mscorlib
  - Stack trace:
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseUInt32(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.UInt16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToUInt16(String value)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetPropertyAppType(DefinitionAppId appId, String propName)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
 No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at: [MS Help and Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942460).  What else you need to do after you follow those steps from Microsoft is to restart machine.  After restarting machine everything should work fine.